# Naming convention for join tables, in a many to many relationship, in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, naming-conventions, join

I have 3 tables.

The first two tables are Groups and Accounts.

- An account can belong to many groups.
- A group can have many accounts.
- In other words it is a many to many relationship.

Therefore I need a 3rd table, which is a join table

What is the recommended naming convention of this join table in Laravel (or perhaps in general).

Is there any naming conventions?

I was planning to call it "GroupsAccountAssignment".

Comment: it should be `account_group`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the pivot table should be `account_group`.

As given in laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

> To define this relationship, three database tables are needed: users,
>   roles, and role_user. The role_user table is derived from the
>   alphabetical order of the related model names, and contains the
>   user_id and role_id columns.

Though, you can always overwrite the default naming convention like below:
Account Model:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'GroupsAccountAssignment', 'account_id', 'group_id');
```

Comment: So what is the laravel command to make the model and migration. I use `./artisan make:model AccountGroup -m` but this will make a table called `account_groups`.

Comment: In fact in this case do I have to even make a 3rd model?

Comment: No.. you don't need to create the the 3rd model

Comment: Laravel will handle the relation without model